# Is it possible to flash an Atmel SAM E70 through a CAN bus without a JTAG?

Tags: microcontroller, flash, can, jtag, bus

My circuit board needs to have both a MCU and a CAN connection so it would be nice to be able to cut down on some of the components.

Comment: As it can probably write to its own program flash, the answer would be "yes" if there is a bootloader on it which accepts data in a way you are prepared to send over CAN.  The next question is if such a bootloader is already on there, or if you would have to install (and perhaps create) it yourself.

Comment: It is not possible to program a blank MCU through CAN. What you can do however, is to write a bootloader which does that for you, then order the MCUs pre-programmed with the bootloader inside.